# How to add date in TEXT type with REAL type

Tags: android, sqlite, date

I am trying to add a Date field which is of type TEXT with 2 fields of type REAL and with the result I have to compare with current date in SQLite. But I am stuck in adding TEXT and REAL to get the calculated date.

i.e. I have 2005-10-01 in TEMP_DATE Field and 15.0 and 4.0 in THRESHOLD1 and THRESHOLD2 respectively. I have to add these 3 fields to get result as 2015-10-20.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote. and please answer the question as well:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQLite, date values can be changed by using modifiers with the [built-in date functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html):

```
SELECT date('2005-10-01', '+19 days');
```

To get the date offset into the required format, use string concatenation:

```
SELECT date(temp_date, '+' || (threshold1 + threshold2) || ' days') FROM ...
```